# horizontally aligning labels with input text

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form that should look like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/g6kQK/

but if I inspect the generated code this is what I get: http://jsfiddle.net/bxA5X/

The problem seems to be with

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

but if delete those attributes nothing changes in my form.

What is the default property for `input type=text` in `html`?

What should I set it to make it aligned with the text?

Thanks.

Comment: ...why don't you just use the code in the first fiddle?

Comment: and why are you writing that much of code... instead of just using, border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; and margin:0; padding:0;

Comment: because that's the generated code I get, my form is inside other divs and css classes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width` from the `.cardno` div, and move the `input` element to the outside.

```
    <label>card no</label>
    <div class="cardno">04</div>
    <input type="text" name="codcard"  maxlength="11"/>
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxA5X/8/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove diplay:block property form.usersetting input[name="codcard"]

Answer (score 0):

here is what i got you the answer hope this is what you want... just see this fiddle

```
   <form id="change_customer_data" class="usersetting" action="/">     

    <label>telephone</label>    
    <input type="text" name="tel" /><br>  

    <label>email</label>&emsp;&emsp;    
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>                

    <label>card no:</label>
    04<input type="text" name="codcard"  maxlength="11"/>
```

```
http://jsfiddle.net/bxA5X/8/
```